# "command 'wine netframework3.exe' returned status 53. Aborting." when installing 'dotnet30' in winetricks

Tags: wine, chromebook, winetricks

this is my first time using askubuntu, so don't bash on me

currently I am using ubuntu 16.04 via crouton on a chromebook; I am trying to install the windows component dotnet30 through winetricks for a program called brawlbox. I'm not sure which part of the log I should put, so here's the entire thing:

```
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Executing w_do_call dotnet30
Executing load_dotnet30
Executing w_do_call remove_mono
Executing load_remove_mono
------------------------------------------------------
Mono does not appear to be installed.
------------------------------------------------------
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
------------------------------------------------------
If install fails, set /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope to 0.  See http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=30410
------------------------------------------------------
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Executing w_do_call dotnet20
dotnet20 already installed, skipping
------------------------------------------------------
Installing .net 3.0 runtime takes 3 minutes on a very fast machine, and the Finished dialog may hide in the taskbar.
------------------------------------------------------
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Setting Windows version to winxp
Executing winetricks_early_wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_dotnet30\set-winver.reg
/home/user/Desktop/winetricks: 1770: test: Illegal number: wine-2.0.1
------------------------------------------------------
Working around wine bug 30845 -- Using native fusion...
------------------------------------------------------
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Executing wine netframework3.exe
fixme:clusapi:GetNodeClusterState ((null),0x32ebc4) stub!
fixme:advapi:DecryptFileA ("d:\\9c506c6b50fece7ce3465c89ed\\", 00000000): stub
err:virtual:map_file_into_view failed to set 00000007 protection on file map, noexec filesystem?
err:module:import_dll Loading library dlmgr.dll (which is needed by L"d:\\9c506c6b50fece7ce3465c89ed\\setup.exe") failed (error c000007b).
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"d:\\9c506c6b50fece7ce3465c89ed\\setup.exe" failed, status c0000135
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command 'wine netframework3.exe' returned status 53.  Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
fixme:msvcrt:__clean_type_info_names_internal (0x64083a50) stub
(xenial)user@localhost:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get update
```

I've searched everywhere for the meaning of 'status 53,' but found nothing. is it possible to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo rm ./winetricks
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/master/src/winetricks

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

Then delete the Wine prefix (this will remove any apps installed in Wine):

```
rm -r ~/.wine
```

Create a fresh 32-bit prefix:

```
WINEARCH=win32 wineboot
```

Then run the Winetricks command again:

```
winetricks dotnet35
```

(`dotnet35` will also install .NET 3.0)

Comment: upon installing .NET 3.0, it yielded the same error; however, running brawlbox after doing all this revealed I needed .NET 4.0 instead of .NET 3.0; the tutorial on installing that application was a few years old, so it must've been outdated. I installed .NET 4.0 without any problems and got brawlbox running, so this answer did solve the problem. thanks.

Comment: What do you get when running `wine --version` in the terminal?